# How inherit css selector to just change width

Tags: html, css

I have a css style defined as....

```
.field_input, .fi { /* input textbox */
    color: #555555;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
```

I want to create 3 new styles that inherit all of these attributes, but changes the width....

```
.field_input_small {width: 15px;}
.field_input_medium {width: 30px;}
.field_input_large {width: 55px;}
```

I know that's not the right syntax. How do I do this correctly? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to inherit, just use it like this: `<input class="field_input field_input_small">`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple css classes to your html elements:

**CSS:**

```
.field_input, .fi { /* input textbox */
    color: #555555;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.field_input_small {width: 15px;}
.field_input_medium {width: 30px;}
.field_input_large {width: 55px;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field_input field_input_small"></div>
<div class="field_input field_input_medium"></div>
<div class="field_input field_input_large"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply all the styles to all the classes

```
.field_input_small, .field_input_medium, .field_input_large, .fi { /* input textbox */
    color: #555555;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Then apply particular style to specific classes like below

```
.field_input_small {width: 15px;}
.field_input_medium {width: 30px;}
.field_input_large {width: 55px;}
```